# Getting wrong values counting how many words contain a character in a String

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

I'm working on a program that gets as an input a String, and loops over each character in the string in order and prints the number of words that contain this character.

For example:

Input : `no i in eye`

Output: `n=2 o=1 i=2 i=2 n=2 e=1 y=1 e=1`

But my code returns wrong values for some characters and I can't figure out where is the mistake.

This is what my code returns :

```
n=2 o=3 i=2 i=2 n=4 e=1 y=2 e=3
```

This is my code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {


    for (String word1 : args) {
        int len = word1.length();
        int counter=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            char letter = word1.charAt(i);
            for (String word2 : args ){
                if (word2.contains(""+letter))
                    counter++;



            }
            System.out.print(letter+"="+counter+" ");
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: In the future, you may want to learn to use the debugger. The debugger is usually useful for finding these "gotcha" kind of errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reset your `counter` after moving to next `letter`:

```
for (String word1 : args) {
    int len = word1.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        char letter = word1.charAt(i);
        int counter=0;                            //here !
        for (String word2 : args ){
            if (word2.contains(""+letter))
                counter++;
        }
        System.out.print(letter+"="+counter+" ");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might need to reset your counter in another location.

edit:
 By this I mean, you should include another `counter = 0;` inside your outer loop.

There has been a response that shows the code example listed above so I won't repeat.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a different loop structure than a `for-each` loop. A `for-each` loop the way you have it written behaves analogously to calling `args.next()` as if `args` was a `Scanner` on an `InputStream`. This means that it increments the read token past the String it returns, and that token cannot be decremented.

You need to access `args` in a different way. Try using `args[i]` inside a simple for loop. This avoids the problem.